# wrap variable in brackets while creating yaml in python

Tags: python

I have below csv file format which I need to convert to yaml.(or below example output)

CVS file format

```
CASSANDRA   a   a
DSE_OPSCENTER       
IGNITE  a   
KAFKA_LEAD      b
KAFKA_SMART     
OAM     
RBM a
```

I used below code to convert the file into expected output

```
datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data_headings = []
for i in datareader:
    new_yaml = open('hosts', 'a')
    yaml_text = ""
    #heading = "["+i[0]+"]"
    #new_yaml.write(heading)
    new_yaml.write('\n')
    for cell in i:
        print cell
        new_yaml.write(cell)
        new_yaml.write('\n')
    new_yaml.close()
csvfile.close()
```

And I get below output which is fine for me.

```
CASSANDRA
a
a
DSE_OPSCENTER
IGNITE
a
KAFKA_LEAD
KAFKA_SMART
...
```

I want a small help here in putting CASSANDRA, DSE_OPSCENTER and so on within square brackets. Something like below

```
[CASSANDRA]
a
a 
[DSE_OPSCENTER]
...
```

**Edit**

I added a template format. But I dont know how to put values in their respective groups

```
HOST_VAR_TEMPLATE = """
[CASSANDRA]
{cell}

[DSE_OPSCENTER]

[SMART]


[SPARK]


[SPARK_MASTERS]


[ZK]
"""

csvfile = open('hosts.csv', 'r')

datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

data_headings = []

for i in datareader:
    print i[1:]
    with open('hosts', "w") as f:
        for cell in i:
            print cell
            f.write(
                HOST_VAR_TEMPLATE.format(
                    cell=cell,
                )
            )
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're talking about YAML? The result looks more like an INI file (or an Ansible hosts list?).

Comment: you are so right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a file with a single document that consists of a multi-line scalar string, followed by an explicit end of document marker. 
You try to write the file yourself, instead of using a YAML library. In principle that is possible, but there are some corner cases where you have to take special care.

You should first load the end result using a YAML library:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

data = yaml.load("""\
[CASSANDRA]
a
a
[DSE_OPSCENTER]
...
""")
```

This will give you a `ComposerError` telling you that `a` (the first one) starts a new document. That is because starting with `[` the parser assumes that the document consists of a single flow-style sequence, and once encountering the corresponding `]`, the document is done.

If you want to have a single, multi-line, string in your YAML file you're best of using a block style literal scalar. This is correct YAML:

```
|
[CASSANDRA]
a
a
[DSE_OPSCENTER]
...
```

If you don't want to run the risk of creating an invalid YAML file, then create a Python string variable `data` and append each line to it including newlines, then write it to file using the YAML library:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import PreservedScalarString

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_end = True


data = ''
data += '[CASSANDRA]' + '\n'
data += 'a' + '\n'
data += 'a' + '\n'
data  += '[DSE_OPSCENTER]' + '\n'

yaml.dump(PreservedScalarString(data), sys.stdout)
```

(the `PreservedScalarString` type wraps your multiline Python string into something that `ruamel.yaml` dumps as a block style literal scalar.

Comment: I added template, as you suggest and this might be a better way to do it but how to put values into their respective groups? I did not use ruamel for this just yet. What is your advice?

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal 1) Do you realise your template doesn't generate valid YAML? 2) If you want to insert multple values combine them in a list, join them ( `'\n'.join(list)`) and insert the resulting string. 3) You should limit the amount of editing to a question, don't make it a moving target.